# How to apply the adapta theme on ubuntu mate

Tags: themes, gtk3, icon-themes

I've seen that amazing [adapta theme here](https://github.com/adapta-project/adapta-gtk-theme) for gnome users. but I am a MATE environment user running 1.16.2 version and GTK3 Version: `3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3`. I know they made one for MATE and I want to fully install it but I don't know how. Can someone list steps for me. And I think you need `ubuntu-tweak-tool` because that's what I used to theme normal Unity Ubuntu. But what do I use to theme on mate?

Comment: It's the same theme and the same method for all supported DEs and those are listed in the same link you posted and yes, Mate is listed. What is your actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

You post link to [its GitHub](https://github.com/adapta-project/adapta-gtk-theme). Have you read whole README.md? :)

It is clearly points to the [PPA with packages](https://launchpad.net/%7Etista/+archive/ubuntu/adapta). So you can:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tista/adapta
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install adapta-gtk-theme  adapta-backgrounds
```

Then go to the *System|Appearance* and select *Adapta* theme variant you like.

I tested this on my Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS MATE. And it works.