# Icon theming tool for MATE desktop

Tags: 16.04, icons

I installed Adapta theme on my Ubuntu MATE 16.04 desktop and I want to apply the paper icon theme here-> https://snwh.org/paper and incorporate it in along side my Adapta theme. I already installed the icon and cursor theme already but I don't have the unity tweak tool and can't use it for MATE. I need a icon theming tool to apply the paper icon theme for Ubuntu MATE 16.04. Does anyone have any recommendations ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply the adapta theme on ubuntu mate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/982326/how-to-apply-the-adapta-theme-on-ubuntu-mate)

Comment: that just talks about the background theme. doesn't say about the icons. i already got the theme applied but now i want to apply a custom icon theme

Comment: https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-mate-customization/ and please try using this website for questions that are hard to find and answer for, not for things Google can tell you in less than a second.

Comment: alright i found the solution. step 1 is go to control center. step 2 is go to appearance. Step 3 while in application preferences, click or tap the button customize and there will be 5 tabs at the top. click icons and you icon themes that are pre or you installed will be in there and just click one to apply the theme

Comment: @VeganTechnology Please do not answer your own question in a comment, if you found a solution post an actual answer including the necessary steps you did in detail so others can benefit from it too.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to get the paper icon theme on Ubuntu MATE 16.04

1. Install paper theme by copying and pasting in the commands from the developers website here

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:snwh/pulp
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install paper-icon-theme
   sudo apt-get install paper-cursor-theme
   sudo apt-get install paper-gtk-theme
   ```
2. Go to System in the menu bar and click on Control Center
3. Click on Appearance under the Look and Feel section
4. After that click on a button called Customize then you will be in a window called Customize Theme
5. There will be 5 tabs at the top. Controls, Colors, Window Border, Icons, and Pointer. Click on Icons
6. Now scroll down till you see the paper theme called Paper and Paper-Mono-Dark.

Answer (score 1):

It is great that you use Ubuntu MATE, but it is strange why you are trying to use `unity-tweak-tool` here.

You can customize MATE DE with the following tools:

- for selecting and **customizing theme** use `mate-appearance-properties` - it is accessed from *System|Preferences|Look and Feel|Appearance* (or *System|Control Center*, then *Appearance* from here).
- for customizing LightDM login screen use `lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings-pkexec` - it is accessed from *System|Administration|LightDM GTK+ Greeter settings* (or *System|Control Center*, then *LightDM GTK+ Greeter settings* from here).
- for desktop icons, interface panel placement (such as selecting Mutiny layout) and window settings use `mate-tweak` - it is accessed from *System|Preferences|Look and Feel|MATE Tweak* (or *System|Control Center*, then *MATE Tweak* from here).
- for default applications use `mate-default-applications-properties` - it is accessed from *System|Preferences|Personal|Preferred Applications* (or *System|Control Center*, then *Preferred Applications* from here).
- for user startup applications use `mate-session-properties` - it is accessed from *System|Preferences|Personal|Startup Applications* (or *System|Control Center*, then *Startup Applications* from here).